# Запятая перед «и» в предложении с вводным словом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, ссп, и

*К счастью, эта мера оказалась недолгосрочной и с 21 января подвоз во все школы возобновили.*
Является ли «к счастью» общим членом, при котором не нужна запятая перед «и»?
Склоняюсь к тому, что запятая все-таки нужна, «с 21 января...» — другое предложение и не связано с «к счастью».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В справочнике Розенталя:

> 2. Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
>
> 4. Общим может быть **вводное слово**, словосочетание или предложение:
>    ***К счастью,** пожар был замечен вовремя и налицо оказались нужные средства для его тушения* — отношение говорящего к высказыванию, выражаемое посредством вводного слова, распространяется на обе его части.

Я бы поставила запятую (теоретически — можно даже и точку поставить; а в предложении Розенталя этого сделать нельзя):
**К счастью, эта мера оказалась недолгосрочной,** [пауза] **и с 21 января подвоз во все школы возобновили.**

К счастью, затмение постепенно заканчивалось, и в прояснившейся комнате явилась добрая фея, положила меня на клеёнчатую лежанку, велела спустить штаны и крепче поджать колени под живот. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]

К счастью, бензина в баке было достаточно, и мы выбрались. [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, запятая не нужна. Разве это не счастье, что подвоз в школы возобновили?